# Connection timeout on oauth2.googleapis.com and bigquery.googleapis.com, when trying to tabledata.insertAll

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timeout

we are making stream inserts directly to a bigquery table and we are randomly receiving timeouts. The google cloud status page doesn't present any problems and we are respecting the quotas and limitations.

Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to bigquery.googleapis.com port 443: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Is anyone having the same problem?

Comment: How do you stream insert? Do you have piece of code?